# Suppress error message from "substitute" if string not found

Tags: substitute

I have this coding in my `.vimrc`:

[image]

If any line contains trailing whitespace, then this function terminates silently, but otherwise I get this error message:

[image]

I could add `silent!` to the autocmd, but I have other code in this function, for which I do not want any error output to be suppressed.

How can I suppress the error message for just this single `substitute` command?

Comment: Check the help for the `:s` flags, see e.g. [`:help :s_e`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As_e) (BTW: you don't need an `:execute` in your function)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can silence individual commands inside a function by prepending `:silent!` just as well, so either `:silent! execute` or `:execute 'silent! %s...` would do.

However, you don't need any of this, because `:substitute` understands a `/e` flag that suppresses any errors resulting from no pattern matches (cp. [`:help :s_e`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As_e)).

Also, you only need `:execute` when you need to interpolate variable contents into a command. Your substitution uses a constant pattern, so you're just making the command more complex (because of the doubling of backslashes) without any benefit:

```
%s/\s\+$//e
```

#### Additional comments on style

- You don't need the `:` in `:call`; this is only needed in (interactive or in a mapping) normal mode to switch to command-line mode. As `:autocmd` already takes an Ex command, it's superfluous.
- The `== 0` is superfluous as well. `'readonly'` is a boolean flag that evaluates to `0` if unset, and `0` evaluates to *false* in a conditional.

Comment: Thanks for your extended explanations. I learned a lot today :-). Just the `if` will remain as is, for philosophical reasons :-).